# NSError - localizedDescription Always Returns Japanese Text

Tags: ios, localization, nserror

I'm trying to pin down an error related to SSL in my app, so I need the exact error descriptions in english, so I can post a (nother) question here with all the relevant information.

***However***, all instances of `NSError.localizedDescription` that I print to Xcode's console appear in japanese.

My app ***does*** support japanese; however:

1. In Project > Localizations, English is set as the "Development Language":

[image]

2. The target's Info.plist lists "United States" as the Localization Native Development Region:

[image]

3. The simulator language is set to English. I even set the **region** to "United States".

Still, when I print `error.localizedDescription` to the console, I get:

> SSLエラーが起きたため、サーバへのセキュリティ保護された接続を確立できません。

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Is that because you enable to use base internationalization that contains Japanese translation ?. Then, if that key is missing from the selected "English" locale, it will fall back to base locale.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely what you say, or what to change...

Comment: I think that I was misunderstanding about this. You just simple printed out "error.localizedDescription" from the console, not using any NSLocalizedString instead. Sorry about this.